# IDE not breaking on exception thrown from websocket controller or middleware

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, websocket, rider

For some reason if exception is thrown specifically from ws controller or middleware - IDE will not break. The socket is closing and thats it. It will on usual http method. I am using Rider, but imagine VS would have same behavior.

Any idea how can I fix it and make IDE break on exceptions in websockets? Thanks.

Example with controller:

```
    [Route("/ws")]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
            using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rider uses its own .NET Core debugger so don’t expect VS to be the same most of the times.

Comment: Server code usually has an exception handler somewhere in its pipeline, which means most exceptions are considered "handled". Debuggers generally don't break on handled exceptions since that's usually just noise. VS has an option to "break when thrown", which always breaks even if the exception is handled; I assume Rider has a similar option.